# Neo4j Path.reverseNodes bug

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using Neo4j 2.2.1. I am trying to use the `reverseNodes` method of the `path` class. Running this code:

```
logger.info("Path1: "+path.toString());
for(Node node : path.reverseNodes()){
   logger.info("Node1: "+node.toString());
}
```

Logger output:

```
INFO: Path1: (469383)--[is_a,722474]-->(469384)--[is_a,732353]-->(469382)--[is_a,722473]-->(469089)--[is_a,722737]-->(468447)--[is_a,722237]-->(467769)--[is_a,721025]-->(467627)
```

We never get inside the for loop. An exception is thrown first:

```
message: "Node[467627] not connected to this relationship[722474]"
exception: "NotFoundException"
fullname: "org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException"
-stackTrace: [15]
O: "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipProxy.getOtherNode(RelationshipProxy.java:189)"
1: "org.neo4j.graphalgo.impl.util.PathImpl$1$1.next(PathImpl.java:205)"
2: "org.neo4j.graphalgo.impl.util.PathImpl$1$1.next(PathImpl.java:187)"
3: "org.eihg.phevor.plugins.TextQuery.path_to_json(TextQuery.java:85)"
```

It looks as though we are starting from the end node but trying to go through the first relationship instead of the last.

Seems like a bug in Neo4j. Am I missing something here?

Comment: please embed your code and error texts in the question. It doesn't help people that would want to answer to have to go to other locations to see it. Also your other places might be gone when someone else looks at the question later.

Comment: And please _*never*_ share code or errors as pictures, always as text, otherwise they are not indexable/findable

Comment: btw `is_a` is not a good relationship-name. Please avoid "general" relationship-names but use semantically meaningful ones.

Comment: Looks like a bug, yes. It would be great if you could raise an GitHub issue on github.com/neo4j/neo4j with a unit test that reproduces the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please also try to reproduce it with the latest version Neo4j 2.2.3 it might already be fixed there.

Comment: is_a is not my choice - I'm using the Human Phenotype Ontology and other ontologies, this is the official terminology they use..

Comment: I could not embed the images because StackOverflow said I didn't have enough points or something. StackOverflow doesn't do syntax highlighting which is one reason an image can be comprehended more quickly.

Comment: StackOverflow does syntax highlighting but you may need to tag your question with the right language–I added the Java tag. I also OCRed your image and included the information as text. Do you have the rest of the stacktrace?